# Pyspark Joining two dataframes with a collect_list

Tags: pyspark

suppose I have the following DataFrames.
How can I perform a join between the two of them so that I have a final output in which the resulting column (value_2) takes into account the number of records to be appended based on the value of the ranking column.

```
    import pyspark.sql.functions as f
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window

    l =[( 9    , 1,  'A' ),
        ( 9    , 2,  'B'  ),
        ( 9    , 3,  'C'  ),
        ( 9    , 4,  'D'  ),
        ( 10   , 1,  'A'  ),
        ( 10   , 2,  'B' )]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['prod','rank', 'value'])

+----+----+-----+
|prod|rank|value|
+----+----+-----+
|   9|   1|    A|
|   9|   2|    B|
|   9|   3|    C|
|   9|   4|    D|
|  10|   1|    A|
|  10|   2|    B|
+----+----+-----+


    sh =[( 9    , ['A','B','C','D'] ),
        ( 10   , ['A','B'])]

    sh = spark.createDataFrame(sh, ['prod', 'conc'])

    +----+------------+
    |prod|       value|
    +----+------------+
    |   9|[A, B, C, D]|
    |  10|      [A, B]|
    +----+------------+
```

Final desidered output:

```
+----+----+-----+---------+
|prod|rank|value| value_2 |
+----+----+-----+---------+
|   9|   1|    A|  A      |
|   9|   2|    B|  A,B    |
|   9|   3|    C|  A,B,C  |
|   9|   4|    D|  A,B,C,D|
|  10|   1|    A|  A      | 
|  10|   2|    B|  A,B    |
+----+----+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Window function and do this before aggregation; In spark 2.4+

```py
df.select('*', 
  f.array_join(
    f.collect_list(df.value).over(Window.partitionBy('prod').orderBy('rank')), 
    ','
  ).alias('value_2')
).show()
+----+----+-----+-------+
|prod|rank|value|value_2|
+----+----+-----+-------+
|   9|   1|    A|      A|
|   9|   2|    B|    A,B|
|   9|   3|    C|  A,B,C|
|   9|   4|    D|A,B,C,D|
|  10|   1|    A|      A|
|  10|   2|    B|    A,B|
+----+----+-----+-------+
```

Or if you don't need to join array as strings:

```py
df.select('*', 
  f.collect_list(df.value).over(Window.partitionBy('prod').orderBy('rank')).alias('value_2')
).show()
+----+----+-----+------------+
|prod|rank|value|     value_2|
+----+----+-----+------------+
|   9|   1|    A|         [A]|
|   9|   2|    B|      [A, B]|
|   9|   3|    C|   [A, B, C]|
|   9|   4|    D|[A, B, C, D]|
|  10|   1|    A|         [A]|
|  10|   2|    B|      [A, B]|
+----+----+-----+------------+
```